# Another copy of splashtop streamer is running

Tags: command-line, splashtop

When I start up this application called splashtop streamer by using `python /opt/splashtop-streamer/SRStreamer.pyc` at the prompt everything works fine.

However, when I add `sh -c sleep 10;` to the beginning of it, the application tells me it's already running and won't open the program. Why?

I'm trying to start the program 10 seconds into the boot of Ubuntu.  When I use simply `sleep 10; python /opt/splashtop-streamer/SRStreamer.pyc` the application does not start.  When I use `sh -c sleep 10; python /opt/splashtop-streamer/SRStreamer.pyc` the application comes up with the error message that another copy is already running, I click okay and it quits.

However it may be important to note that when I'm not booting up the `sleep 10; python /opt/splashtop-streamer/SRStreamer.pyc` command works fine.

Comment: At the beginning of what? Some script? Why `sh -c sleep 10` and not simply `sleep 10`?

Comment: Answering question above.

Comment: have you tried `python/opt/splashtop-streamer/SRStreamer.pyc -p 10`

Comment: that just loads it instantaneously

Comment: Try dumping the command into a shell script, [like so](https://github.com/pacificfils/VariousNothings/blob/master/start-splashtop.sh). `chmod +x` it, and run it at boot-time.

Comment: The question remains, where are you setting this sleep? rc.local? Startup applications? Upstart session job?

Comment: Startup applications... but the script worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend that you try dumping this into a script instead of a single command.

I have taken the liberty of [making a script for you](https://quickmediasolutions.com/pastebin/24/first-non-nathan-osman-paste/). Feel free to use it. If not, a template is below to help you create your own:

```
#!/bin/sh

sleep n; #Causes computer to wait n seconds before moving on to the next line
python /path/to/python/script.py;
```

This will work because it runs everything in a single `sh` process. Basically, it's the exact same as typing both of those commands, one after the other, into a SH prompt.

Once you have the script and have saved it to a safe place. (I like `/home/$USER/.bin/run-this.sh`, run this command in your terminal (any terminal):

```
chmod 755 /home/$USER/.bin/run-this.sh
```

Finally, add it to whatever boot-time solution you want, such as "Startup Items", `init`, `rc.d`, or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Also your `sh -c sleep 10;` should be change to `sh -c 'sleep 10';` and then your command will be change to this:

```
sh -c 'sleep 10' && python /opt/Splashtop-streamer/SRStreamer.pyc
```

[If you want to run your script with 10 seconds delay](https://askubuntu.com/questions/538492/how-do-i-delay-launching-splashtop-at-startup-by-ten-seconds).

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Startup Applications for this, starting the program 10 seconds after login is what happens, so you could use an [Upstart session job](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#session-jobs) instead.

Create a `.conf` file in `~/.config/upstart` (create the directory if needed), containing:

```
description "Splashtop Streamer Service"
start on desktop-start
stop on desktop-end

respwan

pre-start script
    sleep 10
end script

exec python /path/to/python/script.py
```

(Call it `splashtop.conf`, for example.)

The greatest advantage is that Upstart will respawn the program if it crashes, and you can control it using the `start` and `stop` `initctl` commands:

```
start splashtop
stop splashtop
```