# How do I delay launching Splashtop at startup by ten seconds?

Tags: 14.04, startup

I'm trying to delay the command `python /opt/splashtop-streamer/SRStreamer.pyc`
by ten seconds at startup, everything I have tried is failing.  If I remember correctly a command with `sh` at the beginning was the only way I ever got this to work.  I've looked all over the internet for the answer.

Both of the answers work but there's a bug I can't fix that has something to do with these solutions.

Comment: ...and what exactly have you tried? If you give details, it's easier to spot a solution for you. Moreover, it's not clear what you mean for startup. System startup? Your graphic login? Console login? Please edit your question.

Comment: also possible duplicate of [How can I delay a specific program on startup?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/28685/how-can-i-delay-a-specific-program-on-startup)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Execute a command 20 seconds after the desktop is booted](http://askubuntu.com/questions/518503/execute-a-command-20-seconds-after-the-desktop-is-booted)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Prefixing the command with `sleep 10 &&` should do the work if I correctly understood your question. Like this

`bash -c 'sleep 10 && python /opt/splashtop-streamer/SRStreamer.pyc'`

Try **[`man sleep`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/sleep.1plan9.html)** for more options.

Comment: The program won't load at startup with this command.  I think I got it to load before with a sh command.

Answer (score 0):

This is what works: `sh -c "sleep 10 && python /opt/splashtop-streamer/SRStreamer.pyc"` but it's leading to another problem which I posted here: [Another copy of splashtop streamer is running](https://askubuntu.com/questions/524799/another-copy-of-splashtop-streamer-is-running)